# Orientability of top-dimensional manifolds (with boundary)

Tags: manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Is every top-dimensional manifold-with-boundary orientable?  If this is not true, is there an easy-to-understand counterexample?

EDIT: Some context in case this question was unclear. The hypotheses of Stokes' theorem on a manifold-with-boundary $M$ obviously requires $M$ to be orientable. But most statements of Green's theorem (where $M$ is a 2-manifold-with-boundary in $\mathbb{R}^2$) or the divergence theorem (where $M$ is a 3-manifold-with-boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$) do not explicitly require $M$ to be orientable. Presumably, they already are orientable because they are top-dimensional, and although this seems intuitively obvious, I can't seem to come up with an easy proof of this, so maybe it isn't even true.

Interestingly, if one strictly sticks with following definition (from Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*), for example that $x$ belongs to $\partial M$ iff there is an open set $U$ containing $x$, and open set $V$, and a diffeomorphism $h : U \to V$ where $h(M \cap U) = V \cap (\mathbb{R}^{k-1} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \times \{0\})$ and $h_k(x) = 0$, then not even the interval $[a, b]$ is orientable.  As was mentioned in another post, Loring Tu's book fixes this anomaly by allowing only in the one-dimensional case for the right half-space to be replaced by the left half-space.

Comment: Let me suggest an improvement: What you are asking about is top-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$, or to be more explicit, $n$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$. You ought to be aware that manifolds exist in the abstract, they need not be described by any embedding anywhere, and hence the concept of "top-dimensionality" for a general manifold makes no sense.

Comment: Show that they must be open, and thus carry a natural volume form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have answered my own question.

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an $n$-manifold-with-boundary, where $n \geq 2$.  Then $M$ is orientable.

Proof: We first note that since $M$ is a $n$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then points in $M - \partial M$ are actually   interior points of $M$.  For note that $x \in M - \partial M$ means that there is some open set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and an open set $U$ containing $x$ and a coordinate system $f: W \to U$ where $f(W) = M \cap U$.  But by the inverse function theorem, $f(W)$ must contain an open set containing $x$, so in fact $x$ is an interior point of $M$.

Now let $I^n$ be the identity function from the interior of $M$ to itself.  Obviously, $I^n(\text{int } M) = \text{int } M$, so $I^n$ is a coordinate system of $M$, and every point in $\text{int } M$ is part of $M - \partial M$.

We now construct an oriented atlas of $M$ whose volume form is just the determinant on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.  Of course, $I^n$ takes care of all points of $M - \partial M$, with
\begin{equation*}
((I^n)^*\det)(e_1, \dots, e_n) = \det\begin{bmatrix} e_1 & \dots & e_n \end{bmatrix} = 1
\end{equation*}
Now for any $x \in \partial M$, there is an open set $U$ containing $x$, and open set $W$, and a coordinate system $f : W \to U$ where $f(W_+) = M \cap U$ (here we define $W_+$ be the set of all $w \in W$ where $w_n \geq 0$).  In fact, we can restrict $f$ to an open rectangle $W_0 \subset W$ containing $a \equiv f^{-1}(x)$.  By the inverse function theorem again, $U_0 \equiv f(W_0)$ is an open set containing $x$, and moreover $f((W_0)_+) = M \cap U_0$.  Now note that
\begin{equation*}
(f^*\det)_p(e_1, \dots, e_n) = \det Df(p) \neq 0
\end{equation*}
for all points $p \in W_0$.  In fact, by the intermediate value theorem, the above quantity must either be all positive or all negative for all $p \in W_0$.  If the quantity is negative, then we can flip the sign of the first coordinate (we can do this since $n \geq 2$), thus changing the sign of the column $D_1 f(p)$ so that the determinant above becomes always positive.  In this way, we can construct an atlas of coordinate systems of $M$ whose orientations with respect to the determinant is always positive.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say manifold-with-boundary in the theorem statement.